# Convert list of ordered dict to nested lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've list of ordered dict that includes some duplicate Ids in data.. something like this

```
[OrderedDict([('caseId', 20), ('userId', 1), ('emailStatus', 21)]), 
 OrderedDict([('caseId', 20), ('userId', 1), ('emailStatus', 20)]), 
 OrderedDict([('caseId', 18), ('userId', 4), ('emailStatus', 21)]), 
 OrderedDict([('caseId', 19), ('userId', 3), ('emailStatus', 21)]), 
 OrderedDict([('caseId', 18), ('userId', 1), ('emailStatus', 20)]),
 OrderedDict([('caseId', 20), ('userId', 3), ('emailStatus', 21)]),
 OrderedDict([('caseId', 18), ('userId', 4), ('emailStatus', 20)]), 
 OrderedDict([('caseId', 19), ('userId', 1), ('emailStatus', 20)])]
```

I want to get a list of nested lists, something like this;

```
[{
"caseId": "20",
"users": [
  {
    "userId": "1",
    "emailStatus": [
      {
      "emailStatus" : "20"
      },
      {
      "emailStatus" : "21"
      }

    ]
  },
    {
    "userId": "3",
    "emailStatus": [
      {
      "emailStatus" : "21"
      }

    ]

  }
]
},
{
"caseId": "19",
"users": [
  {
    "userId": "1",
    "emailStatus": [
      {
      "emailStatus" : "20"
      }
    ]

  },
    {
    "userId": "3",
    "emailStatus": [
      {
      "emailStatus" : "21"
      }

    ]

  }
]
},
{
"caseId": "18",
"users": [
  {
    "userId": "1",
    "emailStatus": [
      {
      "emailStatus" : "20"
      }
    ]

  },
    {
    "userId": "4",
    "emailStatus": [
      {
      "emailStatus" : "20"
      },
      {
      "emailStatus" : "21"
      }

    ]

  }
]
}
]
```

presenting a nested list like this;

[image]

I tried to achieve this by iterating both lists but couldn't get any idea how to keep record of previous and next records and same data.. that's so confusing.. if anyone can give me a start that how I can iterate my list, it would be very kind of you.

Many regards..

**Updated Question**

[More detailed question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48183771/2660342)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you can use a loop and `dict.setdefault` to group the data in a nested dict:

```
temp = {}
for d in lst:
    temp.setdefault(d["caseId"], {}).setdefault(d["userId"], []).append(d["emailStatus"])
print(temp)
# {18: {1: [20], 4: [21, 20]}, 19: {1: [20], 3: [21]}, 20: {1: [21, 20], 3: [21]}}
```

Or using a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
temp = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for d in lst:
    temp[d["caseId"]][d["userId"]].append(d["emailStatus"])
```

Then, use a nested mixed dict and list comprehension to aggregate your final result:

```
res = [{"caseId": case, "users": [{"userId": user, "emailStatus": [{"emailStatus": s} for s in status]} 
                                  for user, status in users.items()]} 
       for case, users in temp.items()]
print(res)
# [{'caseId': 18, 'users': [{'userId': 1, 'emailStatus': [{'emailStatus': 20}]}, {'userId': 4, 'emailStatus': [{'emailStatus': 21}, {'emailStatus': 20}]}]},
#  {'caseId': 19, 'users': [{'userId': 1, 'emailStatus': [{'emailStatus': 20}]}, {'userId': 3, 'emailStatus': [{'emailStatus': 21}]}]},
#  {'caseId': 20, 'users': [{'userId': 1, 'emailStatus': [{'emailStatus': 21}, {'emailStatus': 20}]}, {'userId': 3, 'emailStatus': [{'emailStatus': 21}]}]}]
```

Comment: Addendum: The `OrderedDicts` in the input actually don't have any effect, but if you want the dicts in the result to be ordered, just use `setdefault(..., OrderedDict())` and also use `OrderedDict([(key, val), ...])` instead of the final dict comprehensions.

Comment: Mind blowing.. that is superb solution with very nice explanations. Thanks a bunch Man.

Comment: @tobias_s
what if we need to group *userName* with *userId*, where to change in following line

**temp.setdefault(d["caseId"], {}).setdefault(d["userId"], []).append(d["emailStatus"])**

Comment: @NullPointer What do you mean? I don't see a field `"userName"` in your dicts. Assuming there is such a field, do you want to combine both to one key? In this case, try `...setdefault(d["caseId"] + d["userName"])...` or something like that. Hard to tell without more info.

Comment: should I create another question or update this one for more detail?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48183771/2660342  Here's link of new question, didn't update this one because of confusion..