# Convert list of ordered dict to nested lists with multiple values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

[With respect to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48166852/2660342) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48167138/2660342) , I've some more queries with some detailed information. So here I'm updating my question

Now data is like this;

```
[OrderedDict([('caseId', 20), ('userId', 1), ('userName', 'user1'), ('emailStatus', 21), ('emailBody' , 'body')]), 
 OrderedDict([('caseId', 20), ('userId', 1), ('userName', 'user1'), ('emailStatus', 20), ('emailBody' , 'body')]), 
 OrderedDict([('caseId', 18), ('userId', 4), ('userName', 'user4'), ('emailStatus', 21), ('emailBody' , 'body')]), 
 OrderedDict([('caseId', 19), ('userId', 3), ('userName', 'user3'), ('emailStatus', 21), ('emailBody' , 'body')]), 
 OrderedDict([('caseId', 18), ('userId', 1), ('userName', 'user1'), ('emailStatus', 20), ('emailBody' , 'body')]),
 OrderedDict([('caseId', 20), ('userId', 3), ('userName', 'user3'), ('emailStatus', 21), ('emailBody' , 'body')]),
 OrderedDict([('caseId', 18), ('userId', 4), ('userName', 'user4'), ('emailStatus', 20), ('emailBody' , 'body')]), 
 OrderedDict([('caseId', 19), ('userId', 1), ('userName', 'user1'), ('emailStatus', 20), ('emailBody' , 'body')])]
```

I want to get a list of nested lists, something like this;

```
[{
"caseId": "20",
"users": [
  {
    "userId": "1",
    "userName" : "user1",
    "emailStatus": [
      {
      "emailStatus" : "20",
      "emailBody" : "body"
      },
      {
      "emailStatus" : "21",
      "emailBody" : "body"
      }

    ]
  },
    {
    "userId": "3",
    "userName" : "user3",
    "emailStatus": [
      {
      "emailStatus" : "21",
      "emailBody" : "body"
      }

    ]

  }
]
},
{
"caseId": "19",
"users": [
  {
    "userId": "1",
    "userName" : "user1",
    "emailStatus": [
      {
      "emailStatus" : "20",
      "emailBody" : "body"
      }
    ]

  },
    {
    "userId": "3",
    "userName" : "user3",
    "emailStatus": [
      {
      "emailStatus" : "21",
      "emailBody" : "body"
      }

    ]

  }
]
},
{
"caseId": "18",
"users": [
  {
    "userId": "1",
    "userName" : "user1",
    "emailStatus": [
      {
      "emailStatus" : "20",
      "emailBody" : "body"
      }
    ]

  },
    {
    "userId": "4",
    "emailStatus": [
      {
      "emailStatus" : "20",
      "emailBody" : "body"
      },
      {
      "emailStatus" : "21",
      "emailBody" : "body"
      }

    ]

  }
]
}
]
```

presenting a nested list like this;

[image]

I tried doing something like this

```
temp.setdefault(d["caseId"], {}).setdefault(str(d["userId"])+str(d["userName"]),[])
```

But it is concatenating `UserId` with `UserName` instead of making new object.. Any guesses please??

Comment: Well, it's concatenating those because you're explicitly converting them to strings and concatenating them. Why are you doing that?

Comment: yes my bad... I've corrected it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of concatenating the `userId` and `userName` fields to one string, you can create a `tuple` of the two and use that as key in the `temp` dictionary. Same for `status` and `body`:

```
temp = {}
for d in lst:
    temp.setdefault(d["caseId"], {}).setdefault((d["userId"], d["userName"]), []).append((d["emailStatus"], d["emailBody"]))
print(temp)
# {18: {(1, 'user1'): [(20, 'body')], (4, 'user4'): [(21, 'body'), (20, 'body')]},
#  19: {(3, 'user3'): [(21, 'body')], (1, 'user1'): [(20, 'body')]},
#  20: {(3, 'user3'): [(21, 'body')], (1, 'user1'): [(21, 'body'), (20, 'body')]}}
```

Or using `defaultdict`:

```
temp = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for d in lst:
    temp[d["caseId"]][(d["userId"], d["userName"])].append((d["emailStatus"], d["emailBody"]))
```

Then unpack those tuples again with `for (uid, uname), status in ...`

```
res = [{"caseId": case, "users": [{"userId": uid, "userName": uname, "emailStatus": [{"emailStatus": s, "emailBody": b}
                                                                                     for (s, b) in status]} 
                                  for (uid, uname), status in users.items()]} 
       for case, users in temp.items()]
print(res)
# [{'users': [{'userName': 'user1', 'userId': 1, 'emailStatus': [{'emailBody': 'body', 'emailStatus': 20}]}, {'userName': 'user4', 'userId': 4, 'emailStatus': [{'emailBody': 'body', 'emailStatus': 21}, {'emailBody': 'body', 'emailStatus': 20}]}], 'caseId': 18},
#  {'users': [{'userName': 'user3', 'userId': 3, 'emailStatus': [{'emailBody': 'body', 'emailStatus': 21}]}, {'userName': 'user1', 'userId': 1, 'emailStatus': [{'emailBody': 'body', 'emailStatus': 20}]}], 'caseId': 19},
#  {'users': [{'userName': 'user3', 'userId': 3, 'emailStatus': [{'emailBody': 'body', 'emailStatus': 21}]}, {'userName': 'user1', 'userId': 1, 'emailStatus': [{'emailBody': 'body', 'emailStatus': 21}, {'emailBody': 'body', 'emailStatus': 20}]}], 'caseId': 20}]
```

Comment: and what for *emailBody* with *emailStatus* ??

Comment: @NullPointer Did not see that there was another change. Fixed.

Comment: God.. I was trying to add emailBody with the help of extend instead of append a tuple.. and on following same procedure, it was giving me error .. You are a savage.